# SQL Server Security Add Execute access to ad group

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I have an AD group with multiple users that I want to give Read/Write/Execute Stored proc access.
I was able to add the group with read/write and map to the database i need. but how do i add execute access to ALL stored procs.. theres about 500 and i know you can add access individually how do you do it as a whole and assign access to my ad group?

Comment: Offtopic, not a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command `GRANT EXECUTE TO [<domain>\<group_name>]`.

This should grant `EXECUTE` permission on the whole database. You can also scope it to a specific schema, for example: `GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[<schema_name>] TO [REDMOND\Corp Users]`.

I hope this helps.